# Evaluate Cos 65

Tags: trigonometry

Please help solve cos 65 ° .
What will be the easiest way to go for evaluation of cos 65 !
I proceeded like cos (45+20) expanded and then for stuck at value of sin20 and cos20 . How will i get it ?

Comment: What are you allowed to do? The easiest way to do it is on a calculator...

Comment: There is no "algebraic" expression for $\cos(65^\circ)$, that is, no expression involving only integers, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, **real** $n$-th roots.

Comment: I know there isn't a direct formula . But we have to reach a numerical value and yes that too without a calculator !

Answer (score 1):

I would write $\cos 65=\cos(60+5)=\cos 60 \cos 5 - \sin 60 \sin 5 \approx \frac 12-\frac {\sqrt 3}2 \frac {\pi}{36}$ where the error is less than  $\frac 12(1-\frac 12 \cos 5) \approx\frac 12\cdot\frac12(\frac{\pi}{36})^2\approx \frac {10}{5200}\lt .002$  The basic idea is to find an angle that is close for which you know the sine and cosine, then expand the difference in a Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

What topics are you covering in class at the moment?

If you are doing Taylor expansions, perhaps just work out the Taylor expansion for cos(65).

Alternately, since 65 = 60 + 5, you could use the cosine addition formula to work out cos(60 + 5). Since 5 is pretty small, you could make an approximation to simplify your work for cos(5).